# Rails 4 Select Not Displaying Selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is a short one. I have a select box that is in a form used to create and edit a group. It works, saves the selected option to the database, but the form does not display what is in the database, it always shows the first option.

```
<%= form_for @group, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :privacy, options_for_select([["Public", "Public"], ["Private", "Private"]],  @group.privacy), {}, {:class => 'form-control'} %>
  <%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

I have also tried:

```
<%= f.select :privacy, options_for_select([["Public", "Public"], ["Private", "Private"]], :selected => @group.privacy), {}, {:class => 'form-control'} %>
```

Again, that save the data but does not display the selected option.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= f.select :privacy, options_for_select([["Public", "Public"], ["Private", "Private"]], :selected => f.object.privacy), {}, {:class => 'form-control'} %>
```

Try this

Comment: That got it, thank you! Didn't see an example like that when Googling for two hours. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<%= form_for @group, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
<%= f.select :privacy, options_for_select([["Public", "Public"], ["Private", "Private"]], :selected => f.object.privacy), {}, {:class => 'form-control'} %>
<%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```